# How to not sort the index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames with one column each. Index of the first is `[C,B,F,A,Z]` not sorted in any way. Index of the second is `[C,B,Z]`, also unsorted.

I use `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)` and get a data frame with 2 columns and NaN in the second column where there is no appropriate value for the index.

The problem I have is that index automatically becomes sorted in alphabetical order. 
I have tried = `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1, names = my_list)` where `my_list = [C,B,F,A,Z]`, but that didn't make any changes.

How can I specify index to be not sorted?

Comment: could you not do `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).reindex(df.index)`?

Comment: That works, thank you. For some reason haven't thought about it

Comment: I guess it sorts all the dfs indices so that it's easier to align them on index, there is probably not much call for preserving the index order when performing this operation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be by design, the only thing I'd suggest is to call `reindex` on the concatenated df and pass the index of `df`:

```
In [56]:
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['C','B','F','A','Z'], data={'a':np.arange(5)})
df

Out[56]:
   a
C  0
B  1
F  2
A  3
Z  4

In [58]:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['C','B','Z'], data={'b':np.random.randn(3)})
df1

Out[58]:
          b
C -0.146799
B -0.227027
Z -0.429725

In [67]:
pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1).reindex(df.index)

Out[67]:
   a         b
C  0 -0.146799
B  1 -0.227027
F  2       NaN
A  3       NaN
Z  4 -0.429725
```